# Cannot find file: 'Chart.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\chart.js\dist\chart.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to impliment a bar chart what am i doing wrong here?

here also i am getting error saying to use typescript

`formatter: (value: number) => value + " %",` 
but i use only .js format

```
import { Chart } from "chart.js";

import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import ChartjsPluginStacked100 from "chartjs-plugin-stacked100";
import "chart.js/auto";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

const ExampleChart = () => (
  <Bar
    data={{
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          backgroundColor: "#EC932F",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          borderWidth: 1,
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
          hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 100],
          borderRadius: 50, // Make Rectangle rounded
        },
      ],
    }}
    options={{
      indexAxis: "y", // Horizontal bar
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          formatter: (value: number) => value + " %", // Add the percentage after the value
          align: "end",
          anchor: "end",
          clip: true, // Hide label if outside of the chart
        },
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          grid: {
            display: false, // Hide x grid
          },
        },
        y: {
          grid: {
            display: false, // Hide y grid
          },
        },
      },
    }}
  />
);

export default function bar() {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <ExampleChart />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what package are you using?

Comment: @DharmikPatel i have added the pakage.json  file in this codesadndbox

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-breeze-wi2h09?file=/package.json

Comment: in code sandbox there is no error

Comment: @when i use it in project only issue comming

Comment: i deleted all my node modules and did npm i still isuue occuring @DharmikPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using typings in `.js` file.

Remove Typings from your formatter function

```
 formatter: (value) => value + " %", // Add the percentage after the value
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://react-rn7jbq.stackblitz.io)

Comment: but i want to keep that in my .js file also can u sujest a alternative to use in .js

Comment: You need to update formatter function as I mentioned above.. try [https://react-rn7jbq.stackblitz.io/](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rn7jbq)

Comment: did u save ur stackblitz it showing a new file

Comment: i think u forgot to save ur code

Comment: oh sorry .. Have a look now!! [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rn7jbq](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rn7jbq)

Comment: still i am agetting the same error

Comment: Cannot find file: 'Chart.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\chart.js\dist\chart.js'.

Comment: delete node_modules and run `npm install`

Comment: i did that stillissue

Comment: oke now its working thankuu